# Can't setMyStatus with google script

Tags: google-apps-script, scripting

I have some trouble with my google script. I try to run this script below in a form but I can't set the status.

```
function onFormSubmit() {
        var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
        var email_address = form.getResponses()[0].getRespondentEmail();
        var date = new Date("insert-date-here");
        var event = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calender-id-here").getEventsForDay(date);
        event[0].addGuest(email_address);
        var guests = event[0].getGuestList()[0].getEmail();
        var status = event[0].setMyStatus(CalendarApp.GuestStatus.YES);
    }
```

The person is added to the calender with no problem but when the row setMyStatus comes it crashes with the error, "Not a user of the event". Can someone tell my why this is happening?

I've even tried to add a very long sleep and tried to fetch the event again. Also if I debug I can see the email of the user I'm trying to add.